Mask-image on element with backdrop-filter breaks when parent has overflow:hidden and border-radius set
I've come across this chrome bug detailed here:
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40778541
Is there any work around to this? Basically, when giving a clipping child's parent overflow:hidden or border-radius, the clipping breaks.
Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/r0vjh3s7/1/
Any help would be appreciated!
I have tried giving it a separate layering render with transform: translateZ(0), but that didn't work :(
Visual table of the problem (Image)
<div class="containerWorking">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="containerNotWorking">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

.containerWorking {
background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 45%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 45%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 74%, rgba(255,0,221,1) 75%);
  padding: 20px;
}
.containerNotWorking {
background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 45%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 45%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 74%, rgba(255,0,221,1) 75%);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.child {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: rgb(50, 50, 50, 5%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(100px);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black, transparent);
}



I do also have to mention that this works normally in Firefox (127.0b5 (64-bit)), issue is occurring in Chromium version 125.0.6422.112

Update: in Chrome Version 125.0.6422.113, the issue happens. But interestingly enough, Chrome Dev Version 127.0.6485.0, the issue doesn't happen-
